# javascript getting substrings in URL

Tags: javascript

In my website I use:

```
- www.example.com/es/index.html
- www.example.com/en/index.html
- www.example.com/ch/index.html
```

How can I easily get the value language? (es or en or ch)

Comment: Change each index.html to a different thing, easy... or get the URL and parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
language = url.split("/")[1];
```

Where url is the URL you are parsing. Maybe use 'location' to get it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var url = 'www.example.com/es/index.html'
var lang = url.split('/')[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

can use `var lang = location.pathname.split('/')[1]`

this assumes that the language directory is always right after `.com`

Answer (score 0):

As u_mulder suggested, you can use `document.location` like so:

```
document.location.href.split("/")[1];
```

Comment: document.location is an object not a string, therefore this just throws an error

Answer (score 0):

While all those

```
str.split("/")[1]
```

solutions are good I want to suggest a regex (if only for completeness sake).

 Using

```
str = "www.example.com/es/index.html";
str.match(/www\.example\.com\/(.+)\//)[1]
```

works aswell and furthermore it also matches correctly for strings like:

```
"http://www.example.com/es/index.html"
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zpmvrv2a/